# Never Received German or Swiss speeding tickets

Tags: germany

A little background information.  In June 2017 I was "blitzed" two times in Germany and one time in Switzerland while visiting friends and family.  Sure enough, I received three emails and three letters in the mail from Enterprise Germany.  I have waited months without receiving any citations from the local authorities from where I was speeding.  Worried, I emailed  the Enterprise Ordungswidrigkeiten department in the email addressing my concern with the Ordungswidrigkeiten numbers hat I have received from them.  I have never heard back from them.  I also called the Enterprise support number here in the states with all the information and my concerns and yet said they would reach out to their European headquarters.  So now being 2019 and I have never heard back with multiple attempts trying to get this resolved unsuccessfully. I am planning on going back and renting a car this summer.  I don't know what else to do or what consequences I will face when I enter Germany.  By the way, I am a dual national (German/American) if there are any additional consequences when I enter the country with my German passport.

Comment: Isn't that your question about the same matter? https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/78241/speeding-tickets-in-germany?rq=1

Comment: I already paid the enterprise processing fees which covers the cost of sending my information to the local authorities that issue my citations.  I have since then not received the tikets to pay.

Comment: Here is a random guess: "Ordnungswiedrigkeiten" don't get you in trouble if paid. Enterprise may have simply paid on your behalf (from the money you gave to Enterprise) and the respective city was happy with it and considers the problem to be solved. By the way, an "Ordnungswiedrigkeit" expires after just 3 months (src: https://www.bussgeldkatalog.org/bussgeldbescheid/verjaehrung/), so if the city didn't send you an invoice yet, then they can't send you one anymore.

Comment: @DCTLib I highly doubt Entreprise will pay the tickets, since what OP paid to them is considered their money for the hassle of relaying his ID to the government, as stated on the contract.

Comment: @DCTLib Enterprise may well have paid the ticket, in order to assure that the issuing countries' police and vehicle registration systems won't flag the vehicle as having an outstanding fine. If Enterprise did pay it, I'd expect them to charge your credit card. That's happened to me in several countries with road tolls. If Enterprise did in fact pay the fine, then I have no idea why they've not charged you. Perhaps, like the rest of us, they just erred and it dropped through the cracks.

Comment: @David as soon as Enterprise provided the authorities with the name of the driver at that time, the vehicle is not "flagged" anymore with outstanding fines (that's anyway not the case in Germany, it's either the driver if known, or the owner which gets flagged).

Comment: @dunni Thanks for the detail. I guess it'll just remain a mystery, or at least until the OP reenters Germany.

Comment: I guess that it remains a mystery even after the OP re-enters Germany as if there is no court order to the like, the immigration officer's computer should not know about any fines when scanning his/her passport.